# Shifting y value using CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios

When using CGAffineTransform to shift the y value of a self.view, does the view start at the top of the navigation bar or in the view that contains the content?

Comment: That will depend on several factors, like what exactly `self` _is_ and possibly whether or not you're supporting iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to iOS 7 0,0 was the top left corner just below the navigation bar.

With iOS 7 and (presumably) following, the top left visible point (not under the navigation bar) depends on the setting of edgesForExtendedLayout.  If edgesForExtendedLayout includes UIRectEdgeTop, then the topmost visible point is 0,64.  If not, the top most point is 0,0.

Comment: Do you know what is by default?

Comment: The default is UIRectEdgeAll.  You can change the setting in storyboards by selecting the view controller and changing "Extend Edges"